# Changing subdirectory of MLflow artifact store

Tags: mlflow

Is there anything in the Python API that lets you alter the artifact subdirectories? For example, I have a .json file stored here:

`s3://mlflow/3/1353808bf7324824b7343658882b1e45/artifacts/feature_importance_split.json`

MlFlow creates a `3/` key in s3. Is there a way to change to modify this key to something else (a date or the name of the experiment)?

Comment: Calling the `create_experiment()` function first before `mlflow.start_run()` might be the solution.

`mlflow.create_experiment('test', artifact_location='sample_path')`

Not sure if you need to set the s3 URI as well, but I will give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented above, yes, `mlflow.create_experiment()` does allow you set the artifact location using the `artifact_location` parameter.

However, sort of related, the problem with setting the `artifact_location` using the `create_experiment()` function is that once you create a experiment, MLflow will throw an error if you run the `create_experiment()` function again.

I didn't see this in the docs but it's confirmed that if an experiment already exists in the backend-store, MlFlow will not allow you to run the same `create_experiment()` function again. And as of this post, MLfLow does not have `check_if_exists` flag or a `create_experiments_if_not_exists()` function.

To make things more frustrating, you cannot set the `artifcact_location` in the `set_experiment()` function either.

So here is a pretty easy work around, it also avoids the "ERROR mlflow.utils.rest_utils..." stdout logging as well.
:

```
import os
from random import random, randint

from mlflow import mlflow,log_metric, log_param, log_artifacts
from mlflow.exceptions import MlflowException

try:
    experiment = mlflow.get_experiment_by_name('oof')
    experiment_id = experiment.experiment_id
except AttributeError:
    experiment_id = mlflow.create_experiment('oof', artifact_location='s3://mlflow-minio/sample/')

with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=experiment_id) as run:
    mlflow.set_tracking_uri('http://localhost:5000')
    print("Running mlflow_tracking.py")

    log_param("param1", randint(0, 100))
    
    log_metric("foo", random())
    log_metric("foo", random() + 1)
    log_metric("foo", random() + 2)

    if not os.path.exists("outputs"):
        os.makedirs("outputs")
    with open("outputs/test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("hello world!")

    log_artifacts("outputs")
```

If it is the user's first time creating the experiment, the code will run into an AttributeError since `experiment_id` does not exist and the `except` code block gets executed creating the experiment.

If it is the second, third, etc the code is run, it will only execute the code under the `try` statement since the experiment now exists. Mlflow will now create a 'sample' key in your s3 bucket. Not fully tested but it works for me at least.

Comment: `...To make things more frustrating, you cannot set the artifcact_location in the set_experiment() function either....`


I was also not able to change `artifcact_location` once exp has been created from `mlflow server` command. But as I was SQL backend, so changed column `artifcact_location` in table `experiments`.